# Zoom meetings fail, error code 1132

Tags: windows, zoom-meeting

A few days ago, my Windows 10 PC became unable to do Zoom meetings, either as a host or guest.  When I try to start or join a meeting, I get an error message like "The meeting has an unexpected error.  Error code 1132".

I'm not the only person this is happening to.  The same issue is being discussed in a Reddit thread titled [Zoom error code 1132](https://www.reddit.com/r/Zoom/comments/g0d696/zoom_error_code_1132/).  I can still use Zoom from all other devices in my house (Macs and iPhones).

One guy in the Reddit thread claimed that resetting his laptop to factory settings fixed the problem, but that isn't an option for me.

I cannot find any documentation on what error code 1132 might mean as related to Zoom [at their site](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204731895-Error-codes-and-messages-for-meetings-and-webinars).  If it is a Windows error code, it apparently means:

```
ERROR_MAPPED_ALIGNMENT 
1132 (0x46C)
The base address or the file offset specified does not have the proper alignment.
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: No response from their tech support (yet).  Apparently, with everyone working from home they have been slammed.  We only have a "pro" account, so no direct ability to call.  Chat windows formerly had a waiting time of 300 people, so they've actually disabled chat.  All I can do is submit a support request and twiddle my thumbs until they get back to me.

Comment: Looking back at my PC's logs, I got a Windows Defender Update right about the same time things stopped working.  I've tried disabling the firewall, but that didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this was not the answer I wanted to post, it is an answer that worked.  After doing everything I could without a full Windows reinstall with disk wipe, that's what I ended up having to do.  It worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

This is using an elephant gun to swat a fly; I suggest trying other solutions first, but since I have no solution for the mystery 1132 error (and apparently neither does Zoom right now...)

[Use Ubuntu on your PC alongside Windows](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/), without removing Windows. Ubuntu's installer has a specific option for this, and [Zoom supports Ubuntu Linux](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204206269-Installing-or-updating-Zoom-on-Linux). Then, you can reboot your PC into Linux, use your PC with Zoom, and access files in your Windows filesystem as needed during the teleconferences.

There are multiple different [flavours](https://www.fossmint.com/which-ubuntu-flavor-should-you-choose/) of Ubuntu available to choose from at https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours ; some are [more Mac-like](https://www.fossmint.com/macos-like-linux-distributions/), such as [Ubuntu Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/). They all are downloaded and created in the same way; almost all use the same installer program, and those which don't ask the same questions during install.

You do not need to actually install Ubuntu to use it; it will run from your LiveUSB (more on that below) without disturbing your Windows operating system, programs, or data files. You can also access your Windows data files with Ubuntu's programs (like using Ubuntu's LibreOffice Calc to open an Excel spreadsheet or Libreoffice Write to open a Word document).

Now, let's make a LiveUSB.

Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download

Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu

[Create a LiveUSB](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/) following these instructions on your Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

A 4GB or larger USB flash drive AKA pen drive is required to make the LiveUSB; it will erase whatever's on the USB flash drive, so make sure nothing's on there before doing this!

Larger flash drives let you set up 'persistence' so you can add programs to the LiveUSB and use them the next time you reboot, or save data files on the LiveUSB you may have downloaded or copied from your Windows drive.

[LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) and many other Ubuntu Linux apps (included, free) are interoperable with Microsoft Office and many other Windows apps; you can open a Microsoft Office file, edit it and save it with LibreOffice, then come back later and use it again with Microsoft Office.

Once you make a LiveUSB, you can either boot your PC with it and use Ubuntu on it [without installing](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started). Yes, this gives you an emergency backup in case Windows completely crashes, one you can use on any PC (or Intel Mac) in your household. If that's all you want, you never need to install Ubuntu Linux on your PC, just use it.

=

If you want to install Ubuntu on your PC alongside Windows, follow these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop

When you get to step 6, Allocate Disk Space, choose the first option, **Install alongside Windows** and tell it to give 30 GB to Ubuntu. It will automatically shrink the [NTFS](https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/definition/NTFS) filesystem of Windows and make its own Linux [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) filesystem to put the Ubuntu OS in.

When it asks where to put [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB), tell it /dev/sda (not /dev/sda1) or /dev/nvme0 if your PC has an [NVMe](https://www.howtogeek.com/404627/what-are-nvme-drives-and-should-you-buy-one/) (aka PCIe) SSD instead of the traditional SATA [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) or [HDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive).

When it completes, it will reboot your PC and thereafter give you the choice of booting into Ubuntu or into Windows each time you reboot or power up.

Superuser.com has an allied Q&A specialty site just for Ubuntu and its flavours at https://askubuntu.com for questions and free support, or you can ask and get help here.

Answer (score 0):

if u are unsure about it use a virtual machine and make shared folders so that u can access files as well I am also facing the same issue some say its bad cache some say its cause your device is banned maybe I would like to know what changes occur when formating a device so that we can pinpoint it and just change that which effects zoom

Comment: I tried going down the virtual machine route with Ubuntu, but it just became too complicated.  Ubuntu wouldn't show video for my webcam, etc., so I abandoned that.  It would only have been a bandage anyway.  I'm still looking for any clues, if anybody has any.  Also, I looked through the Windows Event Viewer for clues there, but there was nothing related.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same issue for the past few months. Today, I clicked host a meeting on zoom's website and it allowed me to sign into my downloaded zoom app (something I haven't been able to do due to the error code). Afterwards, I've confirmed that I can use all the features on zoom and the error seems to have been fixed. This is something you can try as a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue as well when trying to use the destop install version.  The only way I've been able to get around this is by using the Google Chrome internet application and adding Zoom as a Chrome extension or add-on.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a quick solution for this problem.
Just make sure to enable the  "Join from your browser" Link is enabled (from your zoom account settings). And then you can join any meeting from your browser without the need to reset your pc or download an alternative machine

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. Found a work around so you do not need to log out to run Zoom.
Create a different user. Log in as that user and re-install Zoom. Log out and log in as original user.
Create batch file to run Zoom as other user:

runas /user:USER­NAME “C:\Program Files (x86)\Zoom\bin\Zoom.exe”
Enter other user password